# Mostrar fecha con formato en python

Tags: python, django

tengo una pregunta respecto a como puedo mostrar una fecha en python utilizando django.

Resulta que necesito mostrar una fecha en un td, y la llamo de la siguiente manera desde mi view y utilizo un filtro:

```
{{ variable|date: "m/d/y H:m" }}
```

para que me lo muestre en este orden: mes -> dia -> año -> horas -> minutos

Pero mi problema es que no logro conseguir que se muestren los minutos, pues me muestra el mes.
Como podría solucionarlo para que me muestre la fecha en el formato mes/dia/año horas:minutos???

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que quieres mostrar las horas y minutos con el filtro [`date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date), lo cual no es lo correcto, lo correcto seria utilizar el filtro [`time`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#time) para mostrar las horas y minutos.

Y para hacerlo seria así:

```
{{ variable|date:"m/d/y" }} {{ variable|time:"H:i" }}
```

De hecho exactamente este ejemplo se usa en la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date), donde se explica que esta seria la mejor forma de generar una representación completa de un objeto `datetime`.

Y Respecto al filtro [`time`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#time), `H` da un formato de 24 horas (`h` daría un formato de 12 horas), `i` de minutos y `s` de segundos con ceros a la izquierda y así puedes ir personalizando como se mostrara tu fecha, si quieres saber mas, revisa la documentación.

En dado caso quieras un formato así, por ejemplo: *"mes/dia/año horas:minutos:segundos"*, tendrías que hacerlo así:

```
{{ variable|date:"m/d/y" }} {{ variable|time:"H:i:s" }}
```

Incluso podrías conseguir un resultado así (que puede resultar mucho mas legible.):

```
{{ variable|date:"m/d/y" }} {{ variable|time:"H\h:i\m:s\s" }} # 00/00/00 00h:00m:00s
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvió!!